# Hibernate: select for update after select entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Situation: the database stores URLs, and information on how many times they were clicked. Correspondingly, if there is a large load (for example, 100 requests at the same time), there is a great chance for a race condition, and we will, in fact, record a non-actual number of "clicks".
The solution was the following: pessimistic blocking:

```
// entity
@NamedQuery(
    name = "Link.findByIdForIncressClicks",
    query = "SELECT l FROM Link l WHERE l.id = :id",
    lockMode = LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE
)

// spring data jpa repository
@Query(name = "Link.findByIdForIncressClicks")
Optional<Link> findByIdForIncressClicks(@Param("id") Long id);

// service layer
@Override
@Transactional
public Link getLinkByShortCutURL(String shortUrl) {
    Long id = encoder.decode(shortUrl);
    // here i tried use native entitymanager...
    // Link link = em.find(Link.class, id, PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    Link link = linkRepository.findByIdForIncressClicks(id).get();
    link.incressClicks();
    return linkRepository.save(link);
}
```

Everything seems to be ok. READ_COMMITTED level. But the wrong value is still being written to the database (tests via JMeter: 40 clicks, 35 saved)
The select of hibernate in console:

```
Hibernate:
    select
        l1_0.id,
        l1_0.clicks_count,
        l1_0.created,
        l1_0.owner_id,
        l1_0.url
    from
        link_info.link l1_0
    where
        l1_0.id=?
Hibernate:
    select
        id
    from
        link_info.link
    where
        id=? for update
Hibernate:
    update
        link_info.link
    set
        clicks_count=?,
        created=?,
        owner_id=?
    where
        id=?
```

Idk, but hibernate doing first `select entity`,
instead of `select for update` on `id`.

How i can fix that? Maybe i have wrong using pessimistic locks in JPA?

UPD. some details: spring-boot v3.1 (hibernate - 6.2.1.Final)

Comment: what does `here i tried use native entitymanager...` mean? it does not work either?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov that’s means I injected EntityManager into service (I thought that’s bug of spring data jpa, and tried that with EM)

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov upd: and yes, does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by changing version of hibernate. I had 6.2.1, migrated to 6.2.3.
And now i have query:

```
    select
        l1_0.id,
        l1_0.clicks_count,
        l1_0.created,
        l1_0.owner_id,
        l1_0.url
    from
        link_info.link l1_0
    where
        l1_0.id=? for no key update
```

Comment: btw, in your case that would be better (faster) to mark `clicks_count` field/column and non-updatable (`@Column(... updatable = false ...)`) and update/increment it's value via direct update, i.e. `update link_info set clicks_count = clicks_count + :inc where id = :id`